# Castle Windsor - Get Root Component type being resolved

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am using Castle Windsor IoC container and NLog in my project. I am trying to inject ILogger to classes where logging is needed. I want ILogger to be resolved to LogManager.GetLogger(RootTypeName).

Is there a way to get root type name? I tried following, but creationContext.RequestedType doesnt root type.

```
container.Register(Component.For<ILogger>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod((y, creationContext) =>
        LogManager.GetLogger(creationContext.RequestedType.FullName))
    .LifestyleTransient());
```

StructureMap has provision to do it

```
x.For<Logger>().Use(y => LogManager.GetLogger(y.RootType.FullName));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with subresolver...

```
public class LoggerResolver : ISubDependencyResolver
{
    public bool CanResolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        return dependency.TargetType == typeof(ILogger);
    }

    public object Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        return new LogManager.GetLogger(model.Implementation.FullName);
    }
}
```

than add into the kernel,

```
Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new LoggerResolver())
```

and drop your previous ILogger registration.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me after I found SubResolvers must be added before registering any component.

Comment: Awesome, worked great. In my situation I was trying to resolve from ILoggerFactory which I added as a dependency of the LoggerResolver.